# Laravel: How to change language in selectMonth?

Tags: select, laravel, laravel-4

Im using Laravel 4.2.

**Code:**

```
{{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}
```

**Result:**

```
<select id="month" name="month">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

I want to change it to the Indonesian language.

```
<select id="month" name="month">
   <option value="1">Januari</option>
   <option value="2">Februari</option>
   <option value="3">Maret</option>
   <option value="4">April</option>
   <option value="5">Mei</option>
   <option value="6">Juni</option>
   <option value="7">Juli</option>
   <option value="8">Augustus</option>
   <option value="9">September</option>
   <option value="10">Oktober</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">Desember</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

`selectMonth()` uses `strftime()`, which is locale aware. So you just need to change the locale to whatever you'd like, in accordance with the instructions on the `strftime()` manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php